# Добавить fancybox в revolution slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

Добрый день.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Имеются добавленные фотографии в revolution slider, фотографии добавлены со свойством `background-image`.

Мне нужно что бы при нажатии на фотографию слайдера выводился `popup` Фейнсибокса.

Я понимаю что fancybox работает только с тегом `<img>`, и понимаю, что для реализации этого, нужно вытащить `url` `background-image` и создать `<img>`, в котором нужно будет поместить сам `url` и задать правильные свойства.

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой и знает самое оптимальное решение?

Спасибо.

Comment: никак, разве что создашь <img> пустой, будешь подставлять сюда урл картинки и триггером вызывать <img>